# I need a technique for contain every requirement in requested record (SQL-EF core)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

In my cms project I created a "RequestGroup" table for get every need in the current "Content" for example I have a widget "Content" in my homepage "Content" so in that situation I just couldn't find a way.

Currently I'm using EF core for fix this problem. But EF core is not enough for this problem. So I tried sql but I couldn't build a solution on sql too. Need your help, any idea can help. Thank you for your time..

```
public class ContentMain : IdBase
{
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null;

    public Guid RequestGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DetailPage")]
    public Guid? DetailPageId { get; set; } = null;
    public virtual VisualizationMain DetailPage { get; set; } = null;

    public virtual List<SeoOptionContentMain> SeoOptions { get; set; } = new List<SeoOptionContentMain>();

    public string _parameters { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Parameters Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameters>(_parameters);
            }
            catch
            {
                return new Parameters();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _parameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryMain Category { get; set; } = null;

    public Guid DefinitionId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DefinitionMain Definition { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class RequestGroupMain
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? RequestGroupMainId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RequestGroupMain> Childen { get; set; } = new List<RequestGroupMain>();

    public virtual List<VisualizationRequestGroup> Visualizations { get; set; } = new List<VisualizationRequestGroup>();
    public virtual List<ContentRequestGroup> Contents { get; set; } = new List<ContentRequestGroup>();
    public virtual List<CategoryRequestGroup> Categories { get; set; } = new List<CategoryRequestGroup>();
    public virtual List<CategoryGroupRequestGroup> CategoryGroups { get; set; } = new List<CategoryGroupRequestGroup>();
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what your exact problem is? It is difficult to understand.

Comment: Of cource when I import "Content" record in my request process I want to include that record's requirements. That requirements can be "Visualization", "Content", "Category", "CategoryGroup" so I can't figure it out.

Comment: How about `context.ContentMain.Include(cm => cm.Visualizatios).Include(cm => cm.Contents).Include(...`? Sure you've tried that but what's not working with it?

Comment: I didn't try that because of "RequestGroup" I mean I use
Guid requestGroupId = context.ContentMain.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id.Equals({guid})).RequestGroupId;
context.RequestGroupMain.Include(x=>x.RequestGroupMain).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id.Equals(requestGroupId));

Here is my problem, when I get my "RequestGroup" it included "Children" and that "Children" is infinity nested "RequestGroup".. I hope I explaine it.

Some other example, infinity category technique is not work on EF core..

Comment: That's what I need, thank you so much. I changed the system because this situation. But your solution is right answer for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. To cleanly wrap up your post, I've put my two comments into an answer and deleted the comments. Feel free to mark my answer as "the" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is the self referencing parent/child relationship (`RequestGroupMain.Children`).

As you have found out that doesn't work with EF core using only one single query. You can use

```cs
context.Entry(theRequestGroupMain).Reference(rgm => rgm.Visualizations).Load()
```

with some looping and recursion. Of course, if a lot of nested data needs to be fetched in one request, that might result in too many queries.

You can also use a combination of some

```cs
Include(rgm => rgm.Children).ThenInclude(...)
```

until a certain depth and then go further down with multiple calls to `ReferenceEntry.Load()`.

If that isn't feasible (e.g. for performance reasons), you can still go the "raw SQL" path. For this to work your query needs to use a "recursive common table expression (CTE)". Just google for something like "recursive CTE parent child hierarchy SQL server".